# General - How are functions represented in memory?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've tried searching a bit around SO, but I can't find an answer to this question. Perhaps because I can't put it in proper terms. What I want to know is how are functions represented in memory? Instructions must have some storage requirements and we can use function pointers to capture the their locations in memory... Could someone elaborate on this?

The most general notions, specific implementations are not important. And why doesn't sizeof apply to functions? I am really curious about this, I apologize if my notions are flawed from the start (in other words, if I am thinking about it in a wrong way).

Comment: `sizeof` and function pointers are rather language-specific.

Comment: @n.m. - Yes, but I'm curious how the size of functions grows with the number of instructions and local variables. I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, but hopefully some will catch on what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Are you looking for material regarding [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)?

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the link, this answers it partially. But my main question revolves around function pointers. Does a function pointer take a memory address in the classic sense or is it more language-specific? Pointers usually infer how to interpret the linear bytes in memory based on the type and the first byte address. That's where my curiosity turns to functions. If we have function pointers and they take the functions... Do functions give them the address of the first byte in memory and size/type information? Or is that just syntactic sugar?

Comment: I have no idea how to answer your question. I only pointed out that it is not tagged well.

Comment: Function pointers **in C and C++** are very different from data pointers. Specifically, they do not prescribe any interpretation of bytes, and they say nothing about a size of anything. They well may point to something that is not bytes at all, and has no well-defined size. Other languages may differ.

Comment: The following link is specific for x86 architecture, but I think you can extrapolate the idea. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the language.  For compiled languages, functions are represented in memory as machine code; you can generally get [documentation for widely used processors](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) from their manufacturers.

For C/C++, function pointers can be as simple as the address of the entry point to the function, which can be called directly with a single instruction.  I believe this is typical for C/C++ implementations, but the specs do not guarantee it.  In general, the type of a function pointer determines the calling convention of the function:  what arguments it expects to find, and how it returns its results.

The actual code size of the function is not relevant to calling it -- `sizeof(my_function_pointer)` indicates the size of the function pointer, not the function.  Note that even a raw function address may be represented differently from a data pointer (q.v., compilers targeting early [Wintel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) segmented architectures, or embedded processors which may have completely different address spaces for code and data).

For languages in which (unlike C) a function argument may refer to a closure, such a "pointer" would need to include or reference the closure context, as well as the entry point for the function.

Comment: Thank you, that was most illuminating.